# Not able to create ZIP file through Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have small lambda function which donwload files from s3 buckets, create zip of it and upload on S3 bucket again.

My lambda function use .net core3.1.

I can write text file but not create zip file.

Zip File Code in C# (as it deployed in linux system, hence I tried to create zip file in Tmp direcotry)

```
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"/tmp/", "test.zip");
```

Lambda function return below error.

```
Error :
  at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(String archiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode mode, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.DoCreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName, Nullable`1 compressionLevel, Boolean includeBaseDirectory, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName)
   at XXX.DownloadService.CreateZip(DownloadRequest downloadRequest) in D:\Projects\DownloadService.cs:line 133
```

I don't know what did I wrong. or what is alternative to create zip file if this approach is wrong.

Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it is trying to create the Zip file in a read-only directory. The second parameter can include the path of the destination Zip file:

```
public static void CreateFromDirectory (string sourceDirectoryName, string destinationArchiveFileName);
```

> `destinationArchiveFileName`: The path of the archive to be created, specified as a relative or absolute path. A relative path is interpreted as relative to the current working directory.

However, in an AWS Lambda function, only the `/tmp/` directory can be written to. This might conflict with the fact that you are zipping the entire `/tmp/` directory. You might need to put your files in a sub-directory of the `/tmp/` directory:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"/tmp/files_to_zip/", "/tmp/test.zip");
```

Comment: Thanks John, You are right, after add  "/tmp/name_of_zip_file.zip" it works fine. Thanks a lot for answer.